# subtype value can assignable to parent type variable?

Tags: typescript

subtype value can assignable to parent type variable, on the contrary can't, is that true ? i'am confused, if that's true and document say that all types in TypeScript are subtypes of a single top type called the Any type, why any type value can assignable to all other type variable ?

```
interface A {
    name: string,
}

interface B extends A {
    name: string,
    age: number,
}

let a: A = {
    name: 'pony',
};

let b: B = {
    name: 'jack',
    age: 10,
};

// a = b; // OK
// b = a; // fail
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question .. you mention `any` but  your code uses two types `A` and `B` where the exact behavior you describe occurs (a sub type is assignable to a base type reference but not the other way around). `any` is special, it is at the same time a subtype of all types and the base type to all types, making anything assignable to `any` and anything assignable from any.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `any` type to anything simply because using this type is an opt-out from the type checking mechanics of TypeScript. It doesn't mean it will be a correct code. Just the TS won't complain about breaking the rules of polymorphism.

There's a nice explanation of the use of `any` in the [TypeScript's docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any).